# Doubt about the definition of totally bounded metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let $(S, \rho)$ be a metric space. Using my professor's definition, it's totally bounded if for any $\epsilon >0$, we can find $(X_{j})_{j=1}^{J}$ such that $J < \infty$, diam$(X_{j}) < \epsilon$ for any $j$ and $S = X_{1} \cup ... \cup X_{j}$. I'm ok with that.

The problem is that in the next line he says that we can consider every $X_{j}$ as a closed ball, without any loss of generality.

I'm trying to convince myself of that. In the first moment, I thought that we could take the closure of each $X_{j}$, something that would keep the diameter and would close the sets. However, a point $x \notin S$ in the boundary of $X_{j}$ would be included in the reunion, which would brake the decomposition since we wouldn't have an equality between sets anymore.

So, how to see this? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick a point $x_j\in X_j$. Then $X_j\subseteq B(x_j,\epsilon)$. Note that the ball of radius $\epsilon$ has diameter at most $2\epsilon$, by the triangle inequality. Thus, if you can cover the set with finitely many sets of diameter at most $\epsilon$, then you can cover it with balls of diameter at most $2\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ok, so I could take the diameter of any $X_{j}$ to be $\epsilon /2$ and have the result, right?

Comment: Hold on, but there might be other elements in these balls that are not in $S$, so how would I keep the equality between $S$ and the reunion of these balls?

Comment: @RaulGuarini The point here is that you may replace $S=X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_j$ by $S\subset X_1'\cup\cdots\cup X_j'$ as an equivalent definition of totally boundedness. To see the equivalence, just take $X_i=X_i'\cap S$.

Comment: @shrinklemma so let's see if I got it. If you have totally boundedness, you can always use closed balls of radius $\epsilon$ as pre-kidney just showed (name them $X_{j}^{'}$ for each $j$) and have $S \subset X_{1}^{'} \cup ... \cup X_{j}^{'}$. If this can be done, so if we let $X_{j} = X_{j}^{'} \cap S$, we are back where we started and every $X_{j}$ will be closed in $S$. Is this sound? Thanks again!

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I thought $S$ was a subset of a larger metric space rather than the metric space itself. Since $S$ is already the whole space and $S$ is covered by the closed balls, $S$ is equal to the union of these balls.

Comment: In summary, don't think of $S=\bigcup X_i$ as an equality, but rather as a set containment $S\subseteq \bigcup X_i$ (the two are equivalent). The idea is we are covering the set with finitely many small sets.

Comment: Alright so, many thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

(i). If $S$ satisfies the open-ball condition, we can satisfy the closed-ball condition by using $(\bar X_j)_{j=1}^J$ because diam $(\bar X_j)=$diam $(X_j).$

(ii). If $S$ satisfies the closed-ball condition,  then for $\epsilon >0$ let $S=\cup_{i=1}^J T_j$ with finite $J,$
 where each $T_j=Cl(B_{\rho}(p_j,r_j))$ is a closed ball with diam $(T_j)\leq 2r_j<\epsilon /2 .$

Then $X_j=B_{\rho}(p_j,2r_j)$ is an open ball with diam $(X_j)\leq 4r_j<\epsilon,$ and $X_j\supset T_j.$ And  $S\supset \cup_{j=1}^jS_j\supset \cup_{j=1}^jT_j=S.$ So $S$ satifies the open-ball condition.